# Identifing ip address when running whois -h on a linux machine

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, ipv6, whois

when I run the following command, I suppose to get back ip addresses.

`whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route`

this is the result, in some cases it is understandable:

```
//ips end with 0-20
    route:      69.63.184.0/20
    route:      66.220.144.0/20
    route:      69.63.176.0/20
```

in other cases the output is different:

```
route6:     2620:0:1c00::/40
route6:     2a03:2880::/32
route6:     2a03:2880:fffe::/48
route6:     2a03:2880:ffff::/48
route6:     2620:0:1cff::/48
```

What does it means?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it means?

Those are the notation for [IPv6 Addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address).

> route6:     2620:0:1c00::/40
>
> route6:     2a03:2880::/32
>
> route6:    2a03:2880:fffe::/48
>
> route6:     2a03:2880:ffff::/48
>
> route6:    2620:0:1cff::/48

More specifically, these are probably the subnets as they are ending in 0.

Comment: How does PHP REMOTE_ADDRESS would look like? I mean, if I want to block this range in PHP: `2620:0:1c00::/40`  How would i do it in the code?

Comment: I don't have any experience with PHP, but, in general, if it refers to the visitor's IP, then however way visitor's IP is configured, it'd be shown in that way. It can be either 1st way or 2nd, depending on how it is configured at their side.

Comment: @SexyMF - `How would I do it in the code?` Shouldn't this be a separate question as it is totally related to PHP, question reframed in PHP as `how to block a particular IPv6 address in PHP`?

Comment: @SexyMF That has nothing to do with the question you've asked here, and should be asked in a separate question.